System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [42703] ERROR 2624: Column "Username" does not exist
I'm writing to StackOverflow about a recurring problem I have with ASP Core and C sharp WinForm. Each table exists with columns in my database, Vertica. The company where I work uses the Vertica database. I use System.Data.Odbc. Every time I execute a save request, I
have this message :
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [42703] ERROR 2624:  Column "Username" does not exist
If I have, for example, 3 columns like Username, Password and Site, it will be Username does not exist.
If I remove Username from the INSERT, it will be Password does not exist, etc.
I use System.Data.Odbc. Every time I execute a save request, I have this message.
The command read() is working, I can retrieve data from the database. If I execute a SELECT query, that works.
Here is the code :
Anyone not works
Code Simplify for testing:
public void Save(SwissportStateModel model)
{
   OdbcConnection conn = _db.GetConnection();

   string query = "Insert into flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_test (Username) VALUES     
   (@Username)";

   conn.Open();

   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", "John");
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   conn.Close();

}
Normal code :
DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

string cmdstring = "Insert into flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_state (Environment,     
Schedule, IsLaunch, Created_at) VALUES (@Environment, @Schedule, @IsLaunch,  
@Created_at)";

using (OdbcConnection conn = _db.GetConnection())
{
  conn.Open();

  using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdstring, conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Environment", model.Environment);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Schedule", model.Schedule);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsLaunch", model.IsLaunch);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Created_at", localDate);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  conn.Close();
}

Thank you for your help.

Update:
Here are the table definitions.
For table 1:
CREATE TABLE flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_test ( Id IDENTITY ( 1 ) , Username varchar(255) NULL ); 

For table 2:
CREATE TABLE flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_state ( Id IDENTITY ( 1 ) , Environment int NOT NULL, Schedule int DEFAULT 5, IsLaunch boolean DEFAULT false, Created_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL::timestamp );


Can you show the table definition for flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_test?

ODBC doesn't use named parameters. Change @Username to ? in your query. Same goes with other named parameters. Your query should be like: Insert into flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_test (Username) VALUES (?)

Here the table definition ;
For table 1:
CREATE TABLE flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_test
(
Id  IDENTITY  ( 1 ) ,
Username varchar(255) NULL

);
For table 2
CREATE TABLE flexautomatisation.tbl_swissport_state
(
Id  IDENTITY  ( 1 ) ,
Environment int NOT NULL,

Schedule int DEFAULT 5,

IsLaunch boolean DEFAULT false,

Created_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL::timestamp

);

As someone else already mentioned, ODBC doesn't use named parameters, it uses positional parameters.  Using AddWithValue, instead of Add which can make it more difficult to debug your code

If you have a password column, you're doing that very wrong. NEVER store actual passwords in a database. Instead, you must get a HASH of the password, using a cryptographic hash like bcrypt or scrypt (never md5). When someone logs in, you also calculate the salt+hash of the attempted password, and then compare the hashes.

With the help of Yong Shun, I found the solution to this problem.
Effectively, We need to use a VALUES like this: VALUES(?)
The solution can look like this.
OdbcConnection conn = _db.GetConnection();

string query = "Insert into flexautomate.tbl_employee_test    
(Username,Name,Age) VALUES (?,?,?)";

conn.Open();
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", "John");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Doe");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", 45);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();

It works.
Thank you for being so helpful.
